# After Upgrading Ubuntu to 9.10 my hard drive now has a warning

Tags: hard-drive, ubuntu-9.10, mount

I have a 500GB hard drive formatted as ext3: `/dev/sdc1`.

The disk utility does not even see this. This warning is from GParted:

```
e2label: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

dump2fs 1.41.9 (22-Aug-2009)
dumpe2fs: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sdc1

Unable to read contents of this file system?
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
```

Did I lose something during the upgrade of the system? Was it the hard drive or the Ubuntu system that went bad?

`fdisk -l` output:

```
  Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *           1       29164   234259798+  83  Linux
  /dev/sda2           29165       30401     9936202+   5  Extended
  /dev/sda5           29165       30401     9936171   82  Linux swap / Solaris

  Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sdb1               1       59322   476503933+  83  Linux
  /dev/sdb2           59323       60801    11880067+   5  Extended
  /dev/sdb5           59323       60801    11880036   82  Linux swap / Solaris

  Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sdc1               1       59152   475138408+  83  Linux
  /dev/sdc2           59153       60801    13245592+   5  Extended
  /dev/sdc5           59153       60801    13245561   82  Linux swap / Solaris

  Disk /dev/sdd: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sdd1               1       60801   488384001   83  Linux
```

GParted screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Recompile the kernel. It is the only way.

Comment: @taspeotis: Are you a troll or are you trying to do something like a...joke? I can't tell right now and I'd really like to now for the future...

Comment: Could we please get the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: changing kernels often changes the device used to address a harddrive.  your drive probably isn't at */dev/sdc* anymore -- maybe it's */dev/sda* or */dev/sdb* or */dev/sdx*.  you just have to figure out where it is now, and update whatever's trying to access it at the old device path.

Comment: @bobby its the sdc i want to remount without reformatting

Comment: (and yes, ignore @taspeotis, he is either pulling your leg or woefully uninformed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition is still there, but seems to be damaged for some reason. You can try to run a [check](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.ext3), like`fsck.ext3` or `e2fsck` on it, which should be able to repair it.

If that fails, you can also try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) for rescuing your data.

Comment: what options would you recommend

Comment: @Sean: Something like `fsck.ext3 -cf /dev/sdc1` should work.

Comment: i got nothing with that, I then used testdisk and these instructions to use another superblock http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_Find_ext2_ext3_Backup_SuperBlock

it found about 10 superblocks but i got the same error message no matter which one i put in

Comment: @Sean: What is 'nothing'?

Comment: sorry I had no luck mounting the drive while trying to use an alternate superblock

Comment: @Sean: I meant what error messages do you get, and does `dmesg` contain errors?

Comment: I got the data off the drive by plugging it into another machine, I think it has to do with references to the /dev/sdc, gparted doesn't even want to touch it. gparted says:
mkfs.ext3 -L "files" /dev/sdc1
      
mke2fs 1.41.9 (22-Aug-2009)
/dev/sdc1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

Comment: thanks bobby for all your help it was appreciated, if I had more time on this site i would up vote your answer